# how to get the size of a HashMap using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there any way to get the size of a Map using JSTL ? I tried with ${myMap.size} but it's not working..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSTL length function works on a `Collection` but not sure if it will work on a `Map`. Might be worth a try.

Comment: An example, a link, _something_ would make this answer a whole lot more helpful.

Answer (score 30):

got the solution:
Use jstl functions.

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

then use like this:

```
  <c:if test="${fn:length(myMap) > 1 }">
```

Answer (score 12):

```
${myMap.size}
```

isn't working because it gets translated to myMap.getSize() by the EL parser.

Try:

```
${myMap.size()}
```

It should work.

Comment: But ${myMap.size()} is working. In EL #{myMap.size} is converted to myMap.getSize()!

Comment: ${myMap.size()} Didn't work with 1.6.. not that anybody cares ;)

Comment: `map.size()` does not work for `core:if test` evaluation - not sure how you proved that.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example to find the JSTL HashMap size [here](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2014/04/jstl-size-of-map)

We are using HashMap `size` method here

```
${numMap.size()}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just print the count - then you have to use `fn` tags. But if you want to process all the items in a map or do something based on the number of items available, try this using only core JSTL tag:

```
<c:if test="${mapVar != null}"/>
<c:forEach var="mapEntry" items="${mapVar}">
<!-- if there is any entry in the map do something -->
</c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

The above is equivalent to Java Code

```
if (maVar != null && mapVar.size() >= 1) {
    // do something
}
```

Yes you cannot print out the size like this, but you can still process information of the items exist.

I prefered this solution because that SUN url errors out so the above worked for me.